# Prompt user input, getting multiple values

Tags: java

I am working on a basic Java program, whereby the user is prompted to enter it details.
After entering it details, it ask the user if the entered details are correct.
If yes, the user details get printed out, if not the user has to re-enter it details again.

Now the issue is, if the user entered it detail for the second time and they are okay, I get 2 print statement, the old one plus the new one, if they enter it N times, i get and N times print statment.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
     
     public class Calculate {
     
     private String name;
     private float jamb, postUtme, aggregate;
     
     public Calculate(String name, float jamb, float postUtme, float aggregate) {
     this.name = name;
     this.jamb = jamb;
     this.postUtme = postUtme;
     this.aggregate = aggregate;
         }
     
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     public void calResult(){
     System.out.println("Enter your name");
     name = input.next();
     
     
     System.out.println("Enter Jamb score");
     jamb = input.nextInt();
     
     System.out.println("Enter PostUtme score");
     postUtme = input.nextInt();
     
     aggregate = (jamb/8) + (postUtme/2);
     
     confirmDetails();
     
     System.out.println("Dear " + name +  " your aggregate is " +  aggregate);
        }
     
     public void confirmDetails(){
     System.out.println("""
     Correct??
                     \t1 to confirm
                     \t2 to re-enter""");
     int confirmD = input.nextInt();
     if (confirmD == 2){
     calResult();
             }
         }
     
     public String getName() {
     return name;
         }
     
     public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
         }
     
     public float getJamb() {
     return jamb;
         }
     
     public void setJamb(float jamb) {
     this.jamb = jamb;
         }
     
     public float getPostUtme() {
     return postUtme;
         }
     
     public void setPostUtme(float postUtme) {
     this.postUtme = postUtme;
         }
     
     public float getAggregate() {
     return aggregate;
         }
     
     public void setAggregate(float aggregate) {
     this.aggregate = aggregate;
         }
     }
```

Main class:

```
     public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Calculate c = new Calculate("PlaceHolderValue", 0, 0, 0);
     c.calResult();
         }
     }
```

output from multiple entries:

```
Enter your name
Daniel
Enter Jamb score
50
Enter PostUtme score
40
Correct??
    1 to confirm
    2 to re-enter
2
Enter your name
Tobi
Enter Jamb score
30
Enter PostUtme score
20
Correct??
    1 to confirm
    2 to re-enter
1
Dear Tobi your aggregate is 13.75
Dear Tobi your aggregate is 13.75
```

Desired output:

```
Enter your name
Daniel
Enter Jamb score
50
Enter PostUtme score
40
Correct??
    1 to confirm
    2 to re-enter
2
Enter your name
Tobi
Enter Jamb score
30
Enter PostUtme score
20
Correct??
    1 to confirm
    2 to re-enter
1
Dear Tobi your aggregate is 13.75
```

Comment: is this okay...

Comment: You are calling your function twice, `calResult` and there is no if condition.

Comment: And note: your code is really hard to read ... why? Because of the inconsistent indentation. Be really diligent about this things: indent in on opening {, and go back one level after the closing }. Code is written so that HUMANs can read it. Also note: when asking questions here, focus on just bringing the MINIMUM of code here. The only thing that you care right here: that loop, and input/output. That class around it, with all the getters/setters ... doesn't contribute to your problem.

Comment: so, your question is: why does it print the "Dear Tobi" line twice? It's because you call that method twice

Comment: Now I understand where the issue lies, but I dont know what to do.

Comment: You are (perhaps inadvertently) using recursion: you call `calResult` before you come out of the first call to `calResult`. One way to fix this is to use a while loop instead, and make `confirmDetails` return a boolean.

Comment: Call `confirmDetails` from the main function and use return type in `confirmDetails` and `calResult` then do `System.out.println` also in main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example of your problem:

```
public class Input {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        provideInput();
    }
    static String input;

    public static void provideInput() {
        System.out.println("Read name:" );
        input = scanner.next();
        if ( input.equals("false")) {
            provideInput(); // here you recursively call the same method again. That does not mean that the original execution ends.
        }
        System.out.println("input = " + input);
    }
}
```

If I enter "false", and the second time "true",it'll give me

```
input = true
input = true
```

as output.

If you want only once, move the print statement to the calling method:

```
public class Input {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        provideInput();
        System.out.println("input = " + input);
    }
    static String input;

    public static void provideInput() {
        System.out.println("Read name:" );
        input = scanner.next();
        if ( input.equals("false")) {
            provideInput();
        }
    }
}
```

This will only print after the original execution of that method is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The `confirmDetails()` method is invoking `calResult()` which results in additional output.  Everytime `calResult()` is called you are going to have a line of output.  Since `confirmDetails()` is invoked by `calResult()` and may itself call `calResult()` you are producing additional lines of output.

```
calResult() {
  ... stuff happen ...
  confirmDetails()
  output()
}

confirmDetails() {
  ... stuff happens ...
  calResults(..)
}
```

You need to re-organize your code a bit.  One thing that should help is to limit the responsibility of each method. Consider writing methods for each operation and your entry point manage flow of control.  For example.

```
public void calResult() {
  while (true) {
    getUserInput();
    if (confirmDetails()) {
      break;
    }
  }
  double aggregate = calculateAggregate();
  emitAggregate(aggregate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's executing twice because the `confirmDetails();` is called from the same `calResult()`, and after `confirmDetails();` is called, you are printing the value.   So once the first call is executed, the control flow will come back to the first call and will execute the remaining part of the code, which is printing the value again.

The suggestion is to move the confirmation call to be the main class.

Here is sample I have written where the input is taken from Main class itself. But this would give you a better idea.

```
public class Calculate {

    private String name;
    private float jamb, postUtme, aggregate;

    public Calculate(String name, float jamb, float postUtme) {
        this.name = name;
        this.jamb = jamb;
        this.postUtme = postUtme;
        this.aggregate = (jamb / 8) + (postUtme / 2);
    }

    public void calResult() {
        System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your aggregate is " + aggregate);
    }

   //Getters & Setters
}
```

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "PlaceHolderValue";
        int jamb = 0;
        int postUtme = 0;
        boolean retry = true;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
            name = input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Jamb score");
            jamb = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter PostUtme score");
            postUtme = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("""
                    Correct??
                        \t1 to confirm
                        \t2 to re-enter""");
            int confirmD = input.nextInt();
            retry = confirmD == 2;
        } while (retry);

        input.close();

        Calculate c = new Calculate(name, jamb, postUtme);
        c.calResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another concept. The code below just uses [Scanner.nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) and validates all User inputs using the [String.matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with small [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

The `confirmDetails()` method is actually re-written to return a boolean value (true for confirm and false for re-write).

**Regular Expressions Used In Code:**

- `"-?\\d+"` Does the Input match a string representation of a signed
  or unsigned Integer value;
- `"[12]"` Does the Input match a string representation of a unsigned
  Integer value of either `1` or `2`.

**The Code:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String final LS = System.lineSeparator();

public void calResult() {
    String name = "";
    int jamb, postUtme;
    double aggregate = 0.0d;
            
    boolean validInfo = false;
    while (!validInfo) {
        // Name
        String aName = "";
        while (aName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name: -> ");
            aName = input.nextLine().trim();
            // Entry Validation: Is the entry empty?  
            if (aName.isEmpty()) {
                // Yes...inform User and allow for retry...
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry! You must enter a valid name! "
                                 + "Try again..." + LS);
                aName = "";
            }
        }
        name = aName;
        
        // Jamb
        String jam = "";
        while (jam.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter Jamb score: -> ");
            jam = input.nextLine().trim();
            /* Entry Validation: Is the entry a string representation of
               a signed of unsigned integer value?           */
            if (!jam.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                // No...Inform User and allow retry:
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry! (" + jam + ") You must enter "
                                 + "a valid Jamb score! Try again..." + LS);
                jam = "";
            }
        }
        jamb = Integer.parseInt(jam);
        
        // PostUtime
        String postUt = "";
        while (postUt.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter PostUtime score: -> ");
            postUt = input.nextLine().trim();
            /* Entry Validation: Is the entry a string representation of
               a signed of unsigned integer value?           */
            if (!postUt.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                // No...Inform User and allow retry:
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry! (" + postUt + ") You must enter "
                                 + "a valid PostUTime score! Try again..." + LS);
                postUt = "";
            }
        }
        postUtme = Integer.parseInt(postUt);
        aggregate = ((double)(jamb / 8.0d) + (double)(postUtme / 2.0d));
        System.out.println();
        
        // Confirm Entry Details:
        validInfo = confirmDetails();
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your aggregate is " + aggregate);
}

public boolean confirmDetails() {
    String confirmD = "";
    while (confirmD.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Is the above information Correct?");
        System.out.println("  1) To confirm");
        System.out.println("  2) To re-enter");
        System.out.print("Choice: -> ");
        confirmD = input.nextLine().trim();
        if (!confirmD.matches("[12]")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Menu Choice! (" + confirmD + ") "
                             + "Try again..." + LS);
            confirmD = "";
        }
    }
    return !confirmD.equals("2");
}
```